# how to get json array with retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have trouble in the receiving JSON array (Retrofit)

```
{ "ads": [
    {"one": "one a", "two": "two a" },
        {"one": "one b",  "two": "two b" },
             {"one": "one c",  "two": "two c" },

    ]  }
```

Please help me regarding the construction of Model class and how to get , display in the Textview or recyclerView

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) tool to be able to parse json easily using retrofit and/or Gson

To more explanation, follow this [tutorial](http://themakeinfo.com/2015/04/retrofit-android-tutorial/).

Comment: that is a tutorial for retrofit 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Model Class will be like this:-

> Response.java

```
public class Response {

    private List<AdsBean> ads;

    public List<AdsBean> getAds() {
        return ads;
    }

    public void setAds(List<AdsBean> ads) {
        this.ads = ads;
    }

    private static class AdsBean {
        private String one;
        private String two;

        public String getOne() {
            return one;
        }

        public void setOne(String one) {
            this.one = one;
        }

        public String getTwo() {
            return two;
        }

        public void setTwo(String two) {
            this.two = two;
        }
    }
}
```

You can refer to this [codepath guide](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit) in order to get an Idea how to work with retrofit.

Comment: Thank for help ,  But still I do not know how it should main.java, json array in I found